# How to setup VPN on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: vpn

I would like to setup a VPN through GUI. I couldn't do a CHAP, but it was possible to do with MS-CHAPv2 or other options. Do you know where the connection settings are stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't want to be using a PPP based VPN if you have any choices - [MS-CHAP and MS-CHAPV2 are not very secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-CHAP).

A better option is to use OpenVPN - this is also Simpler to set up then a PPP based VPN.

You have not provided details of your operating system, so its difficult to recommend a GUI to you (if one even exists for your OS) - I found [this](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn-gui) for Windows and have used [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.openvpn.openvpn&hl=en) for Android (but I had a configuration file ready for it).